# Random Number Increase Chance - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, random

I have this `int r = arc4random() % 4;` And I want to make it so that 3 has a 70% chance of showing being selected, and 0, 1, and 2 10%. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
int r = arc4random() % 10;
if (r > 2)
    r = 3;
```

though its better to use arc4random_uniform instead:

```
int r = arc4random_uniform(10);
if (r > 2)
    r = 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
r = arc4random() % 9
if (r >= 3){
r = 3;
}
```